# Error: "Property 'self.gameArea' not initialised at super.init call"

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, init

I get the error written in the title. I'm new to this all. Any help appreciated.

This is the GameScene.swift file:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "shuttle")

let bulletSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("torpedo.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)

let gameArea: CGRect

override init(size: CGSize) {

    let maxRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxRatio
    let margin = (size.width - playableWidth) / 2

    gameArea = CGRect(x: margin - size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2, width: playableWidth, height: size.height)

    super.init(size: size)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you to read about [initialization process](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203). Swift preforms two step initialization. First phase is intialization of all stored properties. Also Swift compiler perform few safety checks to make sure two phase initialization is performed correctly. This is from the docs:

> Safety check 1
>
> A designated initializer must ensure that all of the properties introduced by its class are initialized before it delegates up to a
>   superclass initializer.

So you can either initialize your property inside of an initializer:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.gameArea = CGRect()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

or at property declaration (and optionally declaring it as var):

```
var gameArea = CGRect()
```

If you don't make it var, after initialization (at declaration) you won't be able to change it later on. Same goes when you initialize a property inside of an initializer. If it is a let constant, further modifications are not possible.

Comment: Whilst I think you've answered the question with regards what's wrong, this is an area someone far wiser than me could help out LEGIONS of future Swift users, and particularly Sprite Kit Swift users. Understanding the implications of this designed structure and its processes provides a wisdom and insight into how to structure and shape Sprite Kit games, objects, properties and their relationships. This I've only had the barest of glimpses of. But this insight and wisdom would be invaluable in terms of thinking about how to structure and do anything with anything in Swift and Sprite Kit.

Comment: @Confused OPs error was related to non-initialized stored property. I've just pointed him whats wrong. If he wants to go more in depth he should read about initialization process few times. There is nothing related here to the games or SpriteKit. It is Swift in general. Simple question, simple answer :) If he is interested more in depth, he should read docs to get familiar how everything works.

Comment: I'm not so much talking about the OP, nor the nature of Swift as such, but more the implications of the GameScene and didMove(to view... ) etc in terms of thinking about how to plan out and make a game world and its characters and bits and pieces all come together, from conception to reality. I have read that initialisation stuff, many times, and still get caught out on it because Sprite Kit is all based around this first gameScene, and how to use it to do things. Perhaps the legion is me ;)

Comment: @Confused I see. But that was not a question. If it was, I would probably try to answer that. Thanks for the upvote though ;)

Comment: I realise SO is not the right place for this, but I had hoped SO.docs would become something akin to a reservoir of wisdom and insight, since Apple's dropped the ball on providing any meaningful examples for learners and those crossing over. Generally speaking, programmers don't seem keen to attempt to explain things, only to show things. Part of the problem might be pride. Programmers seem to hold tightly to their stake in a shared pride (well earned) at having figured things out despite programming's atrocious literature, documentation and absence of shared wisdom and insight. SO is proof ;)

Comment: and my sincere apologies. curtailing myself to the binary of Q & A probably won't ever happen.